# Force www with .htaccess behind varnish

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, varnish

I want to force www domain behind varnish and apache.

After installing varnish RewriteRule is not redirecting domain.com to www.domain.com

I have:

- apache 2.4.7
- varnish 3.0.5
- several virtual hosts for multiple domains

My .htaccess directive was working very well until I installed varnish.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I already tried to find for the solution but without success.

In my vcl I only configured this:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

All other code is commented.

Comment: Can you post your VCL?

Comment: I added vcl in the post. Basically I configured only backend.

Answer (score 0):

Update your rules with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Not ideal, because it hard codes the domain, but should work :)

The rationale, is that `HTTP_HOST` contains port number and your redirect fails to handle it.

Alternatively, strip port number from `HTTP_HOST` variable using this in VCL:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    # Normalize the header, remove the port 
    set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, ":[0-9]+", "");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answers. Unfortunately none of the above worked. Actually I hoped that hard coding the domain should work, but it didn't.